# GuiSan | SDL2 - Setting colour key of render target results in having an black screen

Tags: c++, gui, sdl2

At the moment i am experimenting with [guisan](https://github.com/kallisti5/guisan) within my little project. Everything is done sofar with **SDL_Texture** except Guisan which utilize **SDL_Surfaces** instead **SDL_Texture** for rendering itself.

Per sé this is absolutly fine. When guisan has finished rendering stuff on its **SDL_Surface** target I simply convert this Surface into an **SDL_Texture** or to be more precise I Update an pre-existing SDL_Texture and then Render this specific **SDL_Texture**. This works perfectly.

Till here everything is fine. I can interact with my GUI and the rest of my application. Then i thought at some point why not use an colour key (*0xff00ff*) to make the target of guisan transparent except for the parts it is drawing his stuff.

So i started calling:

```
 SDL_FillRect(guisanTarget,NULL,*0xff00ff*);
```

To Fill my Target with the colour key i am about to hide away, with this call:

```
SDL_SetColorKey(guisanTarget,SDL_TRUE,SDL_MapRGB(guisanTarget->format,0xff,0x00,0xff));
```

And here is where my problem occurs... if i try to set my colour key the result will be a black screen. No visible GUI to interact with. If I DO NOT set the colour key via **SDL_SetColorKey** then i get my GUI with the background colour i filled my Target via **SDL_FillRect**.

I have no clue why... If anyone has an idea what the reason for this behaviour is please let me know i would appreciate it a lot. see my [issue](https://github.com/kallisti5/guisan/issues/3)

Comment: Be sure to set `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode( yourTexture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);` after you've copied the color-keyed surface into your texture.

Comment: Does not work unfortunately, but thanks for the tip sound reasonable but is not the solution

Comment: Hmm, as I understand it the guisanTarget is an `SDL_Surface`? Under the old SDL backbuffer blitting operations if you didn't want a color you'd color-key the guisanTarget before blitting. You would never need to draw a colored rectangle. Are you using `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`, or `SDL_UpdateTexture`, or `SDL_SetRenderTarget` to get your guisan pixels into the texture? `SDL_UpdateTexture` requires that the target `SDL_Texture` needs to be created with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` access otherwise the `SDL_UpdateTexture` will fail. **Some code would help greatly in solving your problem.**